# If I make edits to a bountied question, do people who have answered get notified of it?

Tags: support, editing, notifications

I have asked a question and put a bounty on it. Looking at the 2-3 answers, it seems there might be a bit of confusion about what exactly I am looking for in the answer. If I add an edit to my question, to clarify it a bit, do the people who have answered get notified of the edit, or will they find out I have edited ONLY if they happen to read the whole question again?

Answer (score 4):

No, answerers do not get notified about edits you make. The only people that get notified about edits are those who [follow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/263383) your question.

In general, there should be no need for such notifications. Note that you should not make edits "in response" to answers, in particular if these edits invalidate existing answers, see also [this recent meta thread](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13502/50583). If you have follow-up questions provoked by the answers you receive, ask a new question instead.

Comment: Edits that clarify what is being asked are fine. If there are answers that misinterpreted the original text, then OP is justified in editing the answer to prevent that type of misinterpretation.